# Smooch - Show Smooch UI inside a UIViewController container

Tags: ios, swift, smooch

I have a container ViewController that acts as a tabController. The container basically handles all of the segue and the viewcontrollers that'll be shown. I need to show the smooch UI within the container viewcontroller. Would any of you know how to do this? The documentation just shows the Smooch UI coming up as a popover or as a segue.

To be more clear, the white space which is a UIView is where I need the Smooch UI to show up. Any help is appreciated!
[image]

**EDIT:** Here's what it looks like after code is implemented [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`+newConversationViewController`](http://docs.smooch.io/api/ios/Classes/Smooch.html#//api/name/newConversationViewController) method to obtain an instance of the Smooch conversation view, and then display it as a child of your tab bar controller

```
UITabBarController* tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];    
UIViewController* convoVC = [Smooch newConversationViewController];

[tabBar addChildViewController:convoVC];
```

### Edit

To add Smooch as a child of a regular `UIViewController`, you can use the following code

```
UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UIViewController* convoVC = [Smooch newConversationViewController];
[vc addChildViewController:convoVC];
[vc.view addSubview:convoVC.view];
```

You'll have to manage presentation of the view controller yourself though, because I believe the view won't have a `Done` button when presented in this way. And if your bottom bar isn't a true tab bar, then the chat input will likely appear beneath or on top of it since the input docks to the bottom of the screen

Comment: Only problem is that the container is subclassing a UIViewController rather than a UITabBarController (don't ask me why) so not sure if this helps

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to add it to a regular `UIViewController`. I'm not convinced it'll display correctly though. Can you explain a bit more about your view hierarchy and why you are using a pseudo `UITabBarController` ?

Comment: I don't really have a reason why I'm using a pseudo UITabBarController. Someone else did it and it's way too painful to rip it out. Basically the Container ViewController has a NavBar and Bottom Tab Bar. Any View shown in the middle is just a viewcontroller initialized then the bar shows the viewcontroller's view. Also see Edit as to how it showed up when I implemented

Comment: That's what I meant by "if your bottom bar isn't a true tab bar, then the chat input will likely appear beneath or on top of it". There isn't really a way to fix this unfortunately. You'll probably either need to hide your bottom bar, or present the Smooch view controller in a more traditional way

Comment: Yeah I realized. Thanks for all the help. I'll probably try to show the smooch UI in a different way instead!